# Game Terrain Database Model

Tags: storage, terrain

I am developing a game for the web.  The map of this game will be a minimum of 2000km by 2000km.  I want to be able to encode elevation and terrain type at some level of granularity - 100m X 100m for example.

For a 2000km by 2000km map storing this information in 100m<sup>2</sup> buckets would mean 20000 by 20000 elements or a total of 400,000,000 records in a database.

Is there some other way of storing this type of information?

MORE INFORMATION

The map itself will not ever be displayed in its entirety. Units will be moved on the map in a turn based fashion and the players will get feedback on where they are located and what the local area looks like. Terrain will dictate speed and prohibition of movement.

I guess I am trying to say that the map will be used for the game and not necessarily for a graphical or display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat it differently, by separating terrain type and elevation.

1. Terrain type, I assume, does not change as rapidly as elevation - there are probably sectors of the same type of terrain that stretch over much longer than the lowest level of granularity. I would map those sectors into database records or some kind of hash table, depending on performance, memory and other requirements.
2. Elevation I would assume is semi-contiuous, as it changes gradually for the most part. I would try to map the values into set of continuous functions (different sets between parts that are not continues, as in sudden change in elevation). For any set of coordinates for which the terrain is the same elevation or can be described by a simple function, you just need to define the range this function covers. This should reduce much the amount of information you need to record to describe the elevation at each point in the terrain.

So basically I would break down the map into different sectors which compose of (x,y) ranges, once for terrain type and once for terrain elevation, and build a hash table for each which can return the appropriate value as needed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to generate your terrain.
For example, you could procedurally generate it all (using interpolation of a low resolution terrain/height map - stored as two "bitmaps" - with random interpolation seeded from the xy coords to ensure that terrain didn't morph), and use minimal storage. 
If you wanted areas of terrain that were completely defined, you could store these separately and use them where appropriate, randomly generating the rest.)

If you want completely defined terrain, then you're going to need to look into some kind of compression/streaming technique to only pull terrain you are currently interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the kind of granularity that you are looking for, then there is no obvious way of doing it.

You could try a 2-dimensional wavelet transform, but that's pretty complex. Something like a Fourier transform would do quite nicely. Plus, you probably wouldn't go about storing the terrain with a one-record-per-piece-of-land way; it makes more sense to have some sort of database field which can store an encoded matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual solution is to break your domain up into "tiles" of manageable sizes.  You'll have to add a little bit of logic to load the appropriate tiles at any given time, but not too bad.

You shouldn't need to access all that info at once--even if each 100m2 bucket occupied a single pixel on the screen, no screen I know of could show 20k x 20k pixels at once.

Also, I wouldn't use a database--look into height mapping--effectively using a black & white image whose pixel values represent heights.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That will be awfully lot of information no matter which way you look at it. 400,000,000 grid cells will take their toll.

I see two ways of going around this. Firstly, since it is a web-based game, you might be able to get a server with a decently sized HDD and store the 400M records in it just as you would normally. Or more likely create some sort of your own storage mechanism for efficiency. Then you would only have to devise a way to access the data efficiently, which could be done by taking into account the fact that you doubtfully will need to use it all at once. ;)

The other way would be some kind of compression. You have to be careful with this though. Most out-of-the-box compression algorithms won't allow you to decompress an arbitrary location in the stream. Perhaps your terrain data has some patterns in it you can use? I doubt it will be completely random. More likely I predict large areas with the same data. Perhaps those can be encoded as such?